# Делегирование реализации интерфейсов

Tags: java, ооп, делегаты

Есть некий интерфейс `A` и есть его наследник интерфейс `B`. У меня есть объект интерфейса `A` мне нужно создать класс, реализующий интерфейс `B`.

Вопрос, кроме прямого объявления всех методов из `A` и вызова соответствующих методов у объекта нет другого способа реализации?

```
interface A  {
  void SomeMethod1(...);
  int SomeMethod2(...);
  ........
}

interface B extends A {
  ........
}

class MyClass implements B {
  private A obj;
  void SomeMethod1(...) {
    obj.SomeMethod1(...);
  }

  int SomeMethod2(...) {
    return obj.SomeMethod2(...);
  }
  ........
}
```

Класс, реализующий `A` неизвестен и недоступен. Так, что отнаследоваться не получится.

Comment: По идее, если у вас 8+ ява (или Kotlin), то можно дефолтные реализации методов в В интерфейсе прописать. Типа добавить геттер для  `obj` и на нём методы вызвывать в интерфейсе. После в `MyClass` надо будет только геттер реализовать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Идея красивая. Но на объем кода никак не влияет. Только дубли вызовы перекочевывают из класса в интерфейс. Профита никакого

Comment: Абсолютно нормальная реализация, называемая композицией.

Comment: Это [шаблон делегирования](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Шаблон_делегирования). Вроде нормальная практика

Comment: @StasDorozhko Я знаю, что это делегирование. Меня интересовало можно ли как-то сократить код, или нужно тупо переписать все вызовы? Как Я понял - ответ нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вдохновленный советом @ЮрийСПБ, Сделал так:

1. Объявил интерфейс

   ```
   interface DelegateA extends A {
     A getObj();

     @Override
     default void SomeMethod1(...) {
       getObj().SomeMethod1(...);
     }

     @Override
     default int SomeMethod2(...) {
       return getObj().SomeMethod2(...);
     }
     ............
   }
   ```
2. Объявил интерфейс `B`

   ```
   interface B extends A {
     ........
   }
   ```
3. Сделал реализацию

   ```
   class MyClass implements B, DelegateA {
     private A obj;

     @Override
     A getObj() {
       return obj;
     }
   }
   ```

Этот способ мне нравится больше, чем предложенный Юрием, т.к. интерфейс `B` теперь не зависит ни от каких делегатов и может быть реализован автономно